# SSRS BIDS expression Show/Hide image based on passed through parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, bids, ssrs-expression

Is it possible to have an image available if a certain field is selected, in this case the parameter is @employeename, I only want the image that has been placed on the report to display if a certain value is true.

What is the syntax, field i am concerned with is employeename

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression would be something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!employeename.Value = "Something", True, False)
```

You can have `"Something"` be a hard-coded value or another parameter. The key thing to remember is you have to access the `.Value` property.

Comment: +1 - and if the condition is on the parameter, then `=IIf(Parameters!employeename.Value == "Something", True, False)`

Comment: Just remember in "Visibility" if your condition returns True, it hides the image and if your condition returns False, it shows your image. (Exactly reverse of what we expect)